# Is there a way stop the mouse wheel from changing settings as i scroll a settings window with slider and drop-down UI elements?

Tags: linux, scrolling, xfce, window-focus, mouse-wheel

I am running Kali Linux with the Xfce desktop environment.

The problem is that when scrolling a window with many settings, the mouse wheel will change any setting that the pointer is over as i scroll.

I understand that this is a feature that was designed for conveniently changing settings, but many seem to agree that it is more of any annoyance since it leads to accidentally changing settings without realizing it.

The research I've done seems to suggest that this is a problem with the way Xfce was developed in GTK3.  In fact, in one of the GTK forums there is a post about "Children of ScrolledWindow receive scroll events when scrolling"(https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/593), which seems to be the technical way to refer to this problem where UI elements within a window receive the focus for the mouse wheel action as the window scrolls under the pointer.

Is there is a way to keep the focus on the parent window at all times while scrolling withing a window?  Or is there another desktop environment that I can switch to that supports disabling the focus switching over each UI element?  At this point, I'll even settle for an easier way to refer to this feature/problem so as to do more research.

I see this question on many forums with no working solution, only many people agreeing with the OP that this is annoying and/or problematic.